# Is there any difference in "doing / having / making a guest spot"?

Tags: meaning

Examples:

Jackson was a fan of the show and called creator Matt Groening one night offering to do a guest spot.

Who should have a guest spot on TV shows?

That guy will make a guest spot on our show tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

> A. Jackson was a fan of Matt Groening, who created ["Family Guy"(?)], so he called him one night to offer Groening a guest spot on his show.
>
> B. Who should be given a guest spot on TV shows?
>
> C. That guy will grace us with his presence in a guest spot on our show tonight.

People do not *do*, *have*, or *make* a guest spot; rather, they can be *offered*, *given*, or *be present in* a guest spot. In each case, *guest spot* is either a direct object of the verb (*to offer/should be given*), or the object of the preposition (*with his presence*), both of which are nouns.  Someone who is better versed in grammatical terms than I could probably pick apart my analysis, but the examples I give should nevertheless be valid.